# What is the correct way to divide a circle in 3 equal-area pieces by dividing it with 2 parallel lines?

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals

> What is the correct way to divide a circle in 3 equal-area pieces by dividing it with 2 parallel lines?

I came up with this question and found a way to solve it but want to know if my attempt at a solution is correct and if it is the most efficient solution. Other solutions are also welcome!
Essentially the question is, on a circle centered at the origin, divide it into 3 equal-area pieces by drawing 2 parallel lines through it, lines perpendicular to the x axis. Where should the lines be drawn? 
For simplicity, I use a unit circle to solve this, and first I rearranged the graph into a function: f(x) = sqrt(1-x^2). Since we can only use the positive or negative square root at a time, I decided to use the positive, and the new area of this semicircle is pi/2, and 1/3 of that would be pi/6. So I created an integral from -1 to x and set it equal to pi/6, and x turned out to be somewhere around +/-0.265.

Is this a valid solution? I would love to see other ways to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: This is a valid solution.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're right. The problem boils down to solving the trascendental equation
$$ 2\int_{x}^{1}\sqrt{1-z^2}\,dz=\arccos(x)-x\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{\pi}{3} $$
which on its turn is equivalent to
$$ \theta-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta) = \frac{\pi}{3} $$
or to $\varphi-\sin\varphi = \frac{2\pi}{3}$ (an instance of [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation)). A step of Newton's method with starting point $\varphi_0=\pi$ leads to the approximated solution $\varphi=\frac{5\pi}{6}$, from which $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{12}$ and 
$$x\approx \cos\frac{5\pi}{12}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\approx 0.2588. $$
Further steps of Netwon's method lead to the more accurate approximation $0.264932\approx\frac{448}{1691}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can construct a coordinate system so that the circle is given by $x^2+ y^2= R^2$.  Without loss of generality we can take the "parallel lines" to be parallel to the y-axis, say at x= a and x= b with $-R\le a\le b\le R$.  Then the three area are 
$A_1= 2\int_{-R}^a \sqrt{R^2- x^2}dx$
$A_2= 2\int_a^b \sqrt{R^2- x^2}dx$ and
$A_3= 2\int_b^R \sqrt{R^2- x^2}dx$.

Do each of those integrals using the substitution $x= sin(\theta))$, set $A_1= A_2$ and $A_2= A_3, and solve for a and  b.

Comment: Simpler is to use symmetry:  $\int\limits_{x=-R}^{-a} ...$ and $\int\limits_{x=a}^R ...$.  These are the same and must equal 1/3 the area of the disk to get $a$.  Never a need for a $b$.

Answer (score 0):

By simple trigonometry, the area of a segment of aperture $\theta$ of a unit circle is given by

$$\frac{\theta-\sin\theta}2$$ and you want this to be $\dfrac{\pi}3$.

With a numerical solver, $\theta\approx2.6053256746009$ and your $x$ is $\cos\dfrac\theta2\approx 0.2649320846028.$

---

An initial approximation can be obtained from the Taylor approximation to the third order,

$$\frac{\theta^3}{12}\approx\frac\pi3$$

but this is not very accurate because $\theta$ exceeds $1$. We can work with the complementary angle $\phi:=\pi-\theta$, giving after rework

$$\phi-\frac{\phi^3}{12}\approx\frac\pi6$$

then $\phi\approx0.53646$ and $\theta\approx2.60513$ by resolution of the cubic.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Jack D'Aurizio's answer
$$\theta-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$ Let $\theta=\frac x2$ to make
$$x-\sin(x)=\frac{2\pi}3$$ and use the approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ which was proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, an Indian mathematician, more than $1400$ years ago.

This leads to the cubic equation
$$4 x^3+\left(16-\frac{20 \pi }{3}\right) x^2+\left(\frac{23 \pi ^2}{3}-16 \pi
   \right) x-\frac{10 \pi ^3}{3}=0$$ which has only one real root and then it can be solved using the hyperbolic method.

The analytical solution is quite ugly but evaluates to $x \approx 2.60528$ while the exact solution is $x \approx 2.60533$.

A faster, almost as accurate, approximation could be obtained building the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant
$$x-\sin(x)-\frac{2\pi}3=\frac {\frac{\pi }{3}+2 (x-\pi )+\frac{\pi}{36}   (x-\pi )^2 } { 1+\frac{1}{12} (x-\pi )^2}$$ and the numerator cancels when
$$x=\frac{-72+2 \pi ^2+\sqrt{5184-48 \pi ^2}}{2 \pi }\approx 2.60545 $$